# unable to type in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

people from StackOverflow. I have a very frustrating experience with VS Code. At the moment of starting a new file, a mode starts on the editor that makes me being unable to type anything. Here is a youtube link from me, trying to type something.
[Unable to type characters in VScode](https://youtu.be/e0sIa1Ut2Ak)

Please, tell me, what should I do?

Comment: Did you restart it? I had a problem where it wouldn't accept touchscreen input until I restarted it.

Comment: For me this has happened when VSCode opened up another window (e.g., showing you where it saves the document), but I didn't know that other window was opened. Once I found it and closed it, everything worked again.

Answer (score 57):

My problem was caused by a **plugin called `vim emulation for Visual studio code`**

I **uninstalled** it and the problem was gone.

Otherwise you can press `i` on your keyboard to return to edit mode.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I contacted the  VScode people from Twitter and they told me that was mi issue.

Comment: thanks, now it working :)

Comment: Yes, worked, thanks! 
I had the same issue in a Mac, and started to work well after deactivating vim.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Gladly I remembered I had installed VIM plugin

Comment: Wow... I can't even believe this is a thing, unbelievable! A HORRIBLE experience, I was ready to uninstall VSCode next. Insane someone thinks this is good. I installed because VSCode actually recommended this extension

Comment: The best solution to dealing with `vim` is always to uninstall it.

Answer (score 53):

press control+C, then press "i" to get in the "insert" status, you could edit your file now.

Comment: This solved my problem as well

Comment: This worked for me, but it was better for me to actually just disable the Vim extension I had, like Rob suggested below.

Answer (score 36):

It looks like you have the Vim extension, or another extension, installed which is causing this. I see `SURROUND INPUT MODE` in the status bar which is probably the cause. Look at your extensions and see whether you need to disable or uninstall one, or start Code with `--disable-extensions` flag to disable them all.

Comment: IT seems that right. The guys from VSCode from twitter told me the same thing in a message. I guess that was the problem. I have 2 files with no issues.

Answer (score 8):

Just press "i" on your keyboard, it should work!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue so I look up to Visual Studio Extensions and Disabled Vim extension then I can now edit my code anytime.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue which was caused by the vim extension. Just go to extensions and type in vim, if it's installed clicked uninstall then reload/refresh vscode. This worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling vim plugin in VS code helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this by starting with the letter `i` while your file is opened and with the cursor at any point on your file. Tapping `i` on your keyboard should immediately take you back to insert mode.

Challenge with this: You have to do it for every file before you start typing.

This is probably the VIM extension. You can keep the extension, all you need to do is `command + C` then `i`. the `i` is to get into insert mode.

To completely solve this problem, you may have to uninstall or disable VIM as an extension

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. all I had to do was disable the vim extension install in my vscode